# Conditions in .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have two domain names examplesite.com and examplesite.net but they point to the same hosting server i.e. website.

Now I have written an .htaccess file because I wanted to show custom 404.html file. 
Here is the code in my .hraccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.examplesite.com/404.html
```

When a user gets a 404 error when he is on examplesite.com he is redirected to the above address which is ok.
But when a user gets 404 error when he is on examplesite.net he is redirected to the above address i.e. 'examplesite.com/404.html' .I wanted the user to stay on examplesite.net/404.html.
I do not want the url for the redirection.
Is there a solution for this? Please help.
Can I apply condition or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The domain prefix is not needed.

Comment: I was trying ./404.html that's why it was not working.\